# Why the same executable in different location loaded different libc.so

Tags: compiling, glibc

I compiled a simple C(only contained an empty main function) file into a.out, and run it in different loaction:

```
user@host:~$ md5sum /home/work/a.out /tmp/a.out
dcbdb836569b99a7dc83366ba9bb3588  /home/work/a.out
dcbdb836569b99a7dc83366ba9bb3588  /tmp/a.out
user@host:~$
user@host:~$
user@host:~$ ldd /home/work/a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe11fa000)
    libc.so.6 => /opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f42b8bca000)    <--
    /opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f42b8f77000)
user@host:~$
user@host:~$ ldd /tmp/a.out
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6ba41000)
    libc.so.6 => /tmp/../lib64/tls/libc.so.6 (0x0000003f0b000000)    <--
    /opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f12f537a000)
```

Why it loaded different libc.so?

---

Here are more information, thanks for @qubert

```
$ readelf -a ./a.out | fgrep ORIGIN
0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN:$ORIGIN/lib:$ORIGIN/lib64:$ORIGIN/../lib:$ORIGIN/../lib64:/opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib:/opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib64]

$ gcc -v -g 1.c 2>&1 | fgrep collect
/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2/collect2 -rpath $ORIGIN:$ORIGIN/lib:$ORIGIN/lib64:$ORIGIN/../lib:$ORIGIN/../lib64:/opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib:/opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib64 --sysroot=/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/sys-root --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o /home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2/crtbegin.o -L/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2 -L/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc -L/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64 -L/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/sys-root/lib/../lib64 -L/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/sys-root/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/lib -L/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../.. -L/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/sys-root/lib -L/home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/sys-root/usr/lib /tmp/ccbKeW7k.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2/crtend.o /home/opt/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/gcc-4.8.2.xxx-r4/sbin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-xxx-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

Comment: Guess: you have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set to something weird.

Comment: @Guess, nope my LD_LIBRARY_PATH = `/usr/local/lib:`. Additionally, `$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/libc.so.6 /tmp/a.out` does not work, but `$ LD_PRELOAD=/opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib64/libc.so.6 /tmp/a.out` is OK!

Comment: It looks like the binary is using  `$ORIGIN` in its `DT_RPATH` or `DT_RUNPATH`; please append the output of `readelf /tmp/a.out | grep ORIGIN` and the output of `gcc -v <your_file.c> 2>&1 | grep collect` to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler was configured to set `DT_RPATH` with `$ORIGIN` by default using its built-in specs.

The purpose of `$ORIGIN` is to create executables that could be moved elsewhere together with the shared libraries they depend on: if a binary is moved to `/alt/opt/bin` and has `$ORIGIN/../lib` in its runpath, the dynamic linker will first look for its libraries in `/alt/opt/lib`. More details in the `ld.so(8)` manpage.

The problem with your compiler is that it's using the deprecated `DT_RPATH` (instead of `DT_RUNPATH`), which is always searched first and cannot be overridden via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. To avoid that, try using `-Wl,--enable-new-dtags` to `gcc`:

```
gcc -Wl,--enable-new-dtags file.c
```

That will direct the linker to use `DT_RUNPATH` instead of `DT_RPATH` for the `-rpath` option, whether set on the command line or via specs. This is supposed to not be supported on older systems, but as far as I remember, that was quite a while ago.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and informative response!